# Is there a way in VB.NET to add an item(s) to a member collection using the initializer list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, initializer-list

Suppose i have this class:

```
class Foo
 Public Property a() As Integer
 Private _l As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
 Public Property l() As List(Of Integer)
    Get
     Return _l
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Integer))
     _l = value
    End Set
 End Property    
end class
```

I am trying to use initializer list to initialize the properties:

```
Dim f as Foo = New Foo With {.a = 1, .l.Add(1)}
```

The above doesn't work. I am getting a bit confused here. Now, in an initializer list from what i understand, i can initialize the collection like this:

```
Dim f as Foo = New Foo With {.a = 1, .l = New List(Of Integer){1}}
```

But what i need to do, since `_l` is already pointing to an object when i say `New Foo`, is only add the elements without saying `..., .l = New List(Of Integer){1}}`
. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Only assignments are supported in an initializer list, you can't call methods.  Just write f.l.Add(1) in the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using [collection initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee358704.aspx), i.e. `Dim f As New Foo From {1, 2, 3}` (see below). However, this has a few drawbacks:

- You cannot use collection initializer syntax and [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) (e.g. `With {.a = 1}`) at the same time. Thus, you'll have to move initialization of property `a` to a constructor.
- Your class must implement `IEnumerable` and have an `Add` method.

That said, here is a working example:

```
Class Foo
    Implements IEnumerable

    Public Property a() As Integer
    Private _l As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    Public Property l() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return _l
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Integer))
            _l = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer)
        Me.a = a
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(ByVal item As Integer)
        _l.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return _l.GetEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class
```

And it can be used as follows:

```
Dim f As New Foo(1) From {1, 2, 3}   ' sets a to 1 and adds 1, 2 and 3 to the list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you can't initialise and add a element to the list at the same time.

As a work around solution you could add a constructor to your class:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal lValue As Integer)
    l.Add(lValue)
End Sub
```

Then you could do this all in one line:

```
Dim f As Foo = New Foo(1) With {.a = 1}
```